# Video Recording - warning: Recording failed

Tags: android, android-intent, video-capture, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

I use `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` intent to open a camera for recording video.
but in some Samsung phones like Galaxy s8 the camera page opens with "warning: Recording failed."
without any logs in the Logcat.

does anyone know what is this?

Comment: Is it happen in a single device or you tested with multiple one?

Comment: i tested in galaxy s8, galaxy tab 10

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem?

Comment: Please, what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your phone camera or microphone might currently be being used by other apps

Comment: Is there a way they can programmatically detect that to prevent this issue, or at least offer a warning?